# ROS Planner Trajectory Sampling Rate

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-industrial

When using ROS Noetic (ROS2 answer great though too) with the Pilz industrial planner, I noticed that the plan output trajectory has 100ms between samples.  I searched the web (and the source-code) but couldn't figure out where this 100ms comes from.  Is there a parameter to adjust it or is it hard-coded somewhere?

I didn't see a parameter for the other planners (CHOMP, STOMP, ...) either.  I get that post-processing can "fill-in" these trajectories, but I'm curious how to increase the planner output density instead.

The pilz source-code has a "plan(...)" function that takes a sampling rate, which seems to be called by a "generate(...)" function which also takes a sampling rate, but I couldn't figure out what calls the "generate(...)" function.

Extra tags: frequency, duration, sampling rate, sample rate, hz, publish rate,

Comment: Hi! Have you had a look at the parameter server to see if you can find anything related to the sampling time of the planner?
Just a hint, as I am not very experienced with trajectory planners...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In case of ROS2

Moveit2 planners inherit the `planning_interface::PlanningContext` and `planning_interface::PlannerManager` classes as shown [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/blob/main/doc/examples/creating_moveit_plugins/plugin_tutorial.rst).

When a planning problem has to be solved then the the `planning_interface::PlanningContext::solve` method of the `PlanningContext`of the planner is called.

In case of the pilz planner the  `pilz_industrial_motion_planner::PlanningContextBase` inherits from `planning_interface::PlanningContext` and `pilz_industrial_motion_planner::CommandPlanner` inherits from `planning_interface::PlannerManager`.

The [solve method](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/include/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/planning_context_base.h#L120) of `pilz_industrial_motion_planner::PlanningContextBase` directly calls the [generate method](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/src/trajectory_generator.cpp#L310) of a `pilz_industrial_motion_planner::TrajectoryController` which then calls its own `pilz_industrial_motion_planner::TrajectoryController` [plan method](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/src/trajectory_generator.cpp#L358) (Note, the plan method is virtual in the TrajectoryGenerator class and only implemented in the TrajectoryGenerator{[PTP](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/src/trajectory_generator_ptp.cpp#L252)|[LIN](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/src/trajectory_generator_lin.cpp#L152)|[CIRC](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/src/trajectory_generator_circ.cpp#L195)} classes respectively).

Depending on the used motion planning strategy of pilz (e.g. point-to-point motion, linear trajectory or circular trajectory) the generator then plans the motion.

In summary, a simplified call stack looks like this (types are left out and names shortened):

```
PlanningContext::solve(res)
↓ is implemented by pilz
PlanningContextBase::solve(res)
↓ calls
TrajectoryGenerator::generate(scene, req, res, sampling_time=0.1)
↓ calls
TrajectoryGenerator::plan(scene, req, plan_info, sampling_time, joint_trajectory)
```

where `res` is a reference to the motion plan response, `scene` is the planning scene of the context, `req` is the motion planning request of the context, `sampling_time` is the sampling rate of your question and `plan_info` is a pilz collection of some scene and req information.

Note, that the `sampling_time` parameter is introduced in the `TrajectoryGenerator::generate` method with a default value of 0.1 (the 100ms you mentioned) and is directly forwarded to the call of `TrajectoryGenerator::plan` but not changed (not even in the point-to-point, linear nor circular trajectory generators calls of the TrajectoryGenerator::generate method - the default value of 100ms of the parameter is used) nor read from anywhere like a ros parameter. Thus the value appears truly hardcoded in ROS2.

The implementation of moveit for ROS1 is different - so it still might be possible there.

Answer (score 3):

```
include/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/trajectory_generator.h:

       planning_interface::MotionPlanResponse& res, double sampling_time = 0.1);
```

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/87148afb11c33d73c35a586ef3330d2d1fa7ba56/moveit_planners/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/include/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/trajectory_generator.h#L109

Found with

```
cd pilz_industrial_motion_planner
grep -r "0.1"
```